# Header redirect not working in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

This line isn't working for me:

```
header("location:landing.php?id=md5($_REQUEST['user'])");
```

I need to pass the `id` variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$id = md5($_REQUEST['user']);
header("location: landing.php?id={$id}");
```

or

```
header("location: landing.php?id=" . md5($_REQUEST['user']));
```

The "md5" is being treated as a string in your current code, remove it from the quotes.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
header('location:landing.php?id=' . md5($_REQUEST['user']));
```

The md5 function shouldn't be in the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: landing.php?id=".md5($_REQUEST['user']));
```

Answer (score 2):

Only variable can be parsed into double-quote (ex.: "$id"). Code need to be evaluate first and then you append the result to your string.

```
header('Location: landing.php?id=' . md5($_REQUEST['user']));
```

There was also a typo in the way you wrote the header, HTTP header name should starts with a capital letter and there is a space after the ":". I'm not 100% sure it needs to be exactly this way, but it's the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in php string concateneate using `.` operator

It should be

```
header("location:landing.php?id=".md5($_REQUEST['user']));
```

Answer (score 0):

!

> Note: HTTP/1.1 requires **an absolute URI** as argument to » Location:  including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: